# Problema de muestra de formulario en React por Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scss

Tengo un problema que al aplicar el 'import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";' no me muestra el formulario y al sacarlo, el fomulario me muestra pero sin los estilos aplicados

Debe ser un problema de que se deben estar pisando los estilos, sino nose, ni chatgpt me pudo ayudar

Adjunto repositorio para mayor detalle: https://github.com/JulianCappellari/09-calendario-app

Como se puede apreciar, en la primera imagen se ve el formulario con todos sus campos pero sin los estilos aplicados, eso es porque el import no esta en el codigo

En la segunda imagen, el import esta en el codigo pero no se muestra en el formulario pero si aparece como el fondo un poco mas oscuro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
CalendarioModal.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";

// Importa los estilos de Bootstrap 5
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const customStyles = {
  content: {
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    right: "auto",
    bottom: "auto",
    marginRight: "-50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  },
};

Modal.setAppElement("#root");

const CalendarioModal = () => {
  // Estado del modal
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

  // Función para abrir el modal
  const openModal = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  };

  // Función a ejecutar después de abrir el modal
  const afterOpenModal = () => {
    // Puedes dejarla vacía si no necesitas nada específico
  };

  // Función para cerrar el modal
  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(false);
  };

  // JSX del componente
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Botón para abrir el modal */}
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={openModal}>
        Abrir Modal
      </button>

      {/* Componente Modal */}
      <Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
        style={customStyles}
        contentLabel="Example Modal"
        className="modal"
        overlayClassName="modal-fondo"
        closeTimeoutMS={200}
      >
        {/* Contenido del modal */}
        <h1>Nuevo evento</h1>
        <hr />

        {/* Formulario */}
        {modalIsOpen && (
          <form className="container">
            <div className="mb-2">
              <label htmlFor="fechaInicio" className="form-label">
                Fecha y hora inicio
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="fechaInicio"
                placeholder="Fecha inicio"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="mb-2">
              <label htmlFor="fechaFin" className="form-label">
                Fecha y hora fin
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="fechaFin"
                placeholder="Fecha fin"
              />
            </div>

            <hr />
            <div className="mb-2">
              <label htmlFor="titulo" className="form-label">
                Título y notas
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="titulo"
                placeholder="Título del evento"
                name="title"
                autoComplete="off"
              />
              <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
                Una descripción corta
              </small>
            </div>

            <div className="mb-2">
              <textarea
                className="form-control"
                id="notas"
                placeholder="Notas"
                rows="5"
                name="notes"
              ></textarea>
              <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
                Información adicional
              </small>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">
              <i className="far fa-save"></i>
              <span> Guardar</span>
            </button>
          </form>
        )}

        {/* Botón para cerrar el modal */}
        <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={closeModal}>
          Cerrar
        </button>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CalendarioModal;
```

_modal.scss

```
/* Modal */
.ReactModalPortal > div{
    opacity: 0;
}
.ReactModalPortal .ReactModal__Overlay {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 999;
}
.modal-fondo {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
.ReactModalPortal .ReactModal__Overlay--after-open {
    opacity: 1;
}
.ReactModalPortal .ReactModal__Overlay--before-close {
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    max-height: 620px;
    max-width: 500px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;  /* Agrega esta línea */
    top: 50%;           /* Agrega esta línea */
    left: 50%;          /* Agrega esta línea */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* Agrega esta línea */
  }
```